# Chaining __getitem__ (d['a']['b']) not working with custom dict wrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, chaining

I have a dictionary where each key is always prepended with a particular string. The dict can look like this:

```
d = {
    "aa123":{
        "aa456": "456",
        "aa789": "789"
    }
}
```

So I am writing a wrapper where I can just query the dict without using the prepended string. Eg:

```
print(d["123"]["456"]) # --> should print "456"
```

So here's my wrapper:

```
class CustDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ns = kwargs.pop("namespace")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = f"{self.ns}{key}"
        return super().__getitem__(key)
```

When I use it I get the following error:

```
cust_d = CustDict(d, namespace="aa")
print(cust_d["123"]["456"])
```

I get the error:

```
KeyError: '456'
```

Now, I know this is happening because `__getitem__` is returning an instance of `dict` instead of `CustDict`.
But if I replace `return super().__getitem__(key)` with `return CustDict(k, namespace=self.ns)` I get other errors like `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Any solution for this would be appreciated.

Comment: before even getting that far, even simply trying to print `cust_d` throws an error

Comment: Oops, pasted the wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, since you want to override the instance method of `__getitem__` then you should not be subclassing from `dict`. If you inherit from `dict` then it will not even look at the instance method of `__getitem__`. You can learn more about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup). Instead use [UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict).

Some slight modifications to your code then make it look like the following:

```
from collections import UserDict

class CustDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ns = kwargs.pop("namespace")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = f"{self.ns}{key}"
        val = super().__getitem__(key)
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            return CustDict(val, namespace=self.ns)
        else:
            return val

cust_d = CustDict(d, namespace="aa")

cust_d["123"]
>> {'aa456': '456', 'aa789': '789'}

cust_d["123"]["456"]
>> '456'
```

Comment: It *will* look at `__getitem__` when you call `custom[whatever]`, it just won't use it in *other* places where you might expect it. Your first link has nothing to do with this.  But generally, yes, subclassing a built-in type will not work exactly as one might *hope* because, for example, `.update` will not use `__setitem__`. The implementation rely on internals for efficiency. You should also explain `CustDict(val, namespace=self.ns)` which is sort of the central error

Comment: Ahh this is perfect! Thank you!!